# find position of element with css property value jquery

Tags: jquery, css

How to find position of element with css property value jquery

```
<ul>
    <li style="z-index:8">aa</li>
    <li style="z-index:4">bb</li>
    <li style="z-index:7">cc</li>
</ul>
```

so how can i find the position of element with `z-index : 4`

Comment: Do you mean position on the page or position in the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you mean by 'position,' but if it's the position amongst its siblings, I'd suggest:

```
var index = $('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('z-index') == '4';
}).index();
```

Whereas if it's the position on the page:

```
var position = $('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('z-index') == '4';
}).position(),
    xCoord = position.left,
    yCoord = position.top;
```

Or position in relation to its offset parent:

```
var offset = $('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('z-index') == '4';
}).offset(),
    xCoord = offset.left,
    yCoord = offset.top;
```

Do remember, and I say this belatedly, that to get a non-`auto` value from the `z-index` property-declaration, you'll have to set the `position` property to another value than the (default) `static` (`relative`, for example, or `absolute`).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).
- [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Comment: @DavidThomas  Tried that on fiddle ,, but `.css()` is returning `auto` `---->`  http://jsfiddle.net/M2DZ6/

Comment: @pXL: yeah, I was assuming, with no basis whatsoever, that the OP would know to change the `position` from the default `static` (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M2DZ6/2/). I've since explicitly added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
$("li").each(function(){
      if($(this).css('z-index') == "4") {
          alert("The index is " + $(this).index());
      }
});
```

You can also use positon for the left and top positions like

```
var lft = $(this).position().left;
var rght = $(this).position().top;
```